# Powershell Remove-Item %1 (Context Menu)

Tags: powershell

Been fighting with Powershell to do what I need it to do. It might be a simple solution but I've not found it.
If this question is a duplicate, I do apologize, but I couldn't find the answer I was looking for.

TL;DR at the bottom.

So, to the issue I have. 
I'm trying to add a PS script to context menu via regedit that deletes a folder + files within, it works great on folders without any spaces in it but when I try to delete a folder with spaces (like "New Folder") it throws an error and closes.
(Tried looking for a pause / sleep command with Remove-Item but no luck, except for long scripts with error handling etc.)

I suspect the error is similar to

```
Remove-Item : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Folder'.
```

> At line:1 char:12
>   + Remove-item <<<<  New Folder
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Remove-Item], ParameterBindingException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand

And the code I'm currently using is

```
cmd /c  PowerShell Remove-Item "%1" -recurse -force
```

I've tried different variations for it to work without luck.
I.E replacing `"%1"` with "pathAsString", added another `"% 1"`, added wildcard `"* *"`, removed the flags. 
Some different variations on the code I've tried:

```
cmd /c PowerShell Remove-Item \"%1\" -recurse -force
cmd /c PowerShell Remove-Item & "{"%1" -recurse -force"}"
```

TL;DR
`cmd /c  PowerShell Remove-Item "%1" -recurse -force` ignores folders with white spaces, tried various things.
Usage in Context Menu (via Regedit).

Might be a solution that's obvious but I don't see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following worked for me:

```
cmd /c PowerShell -command "& {Remove-Item -path '%1' -recurse -force -confirm:$false}"
```

When using cmd.exe, there is no such thing as a script block. This means the value passed to `-command` will always be a string. I added the single quotes `('')` around `%1` to keep your double quotes `("")` with your argument. Apparently, this method will fail if you have a single quote `(')` in your file path. Also the call operator `&` is not required even though the online documentation says it is.

See [PowerShell.exe Command-Line Help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/components/console/powershell.exe-command-line-help?view=powershell-6) for more information on how to use `PowerShell.exe`.

See [About Quoting Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-6) for more information on how PowerShell single and double quotation marks work.

Answer (score 0):

One of your attempts:

> `cmd /c PowerShell Remove-Item \"%1\" -recurse -force`

actually *does* work, albeit only if those paths that have embedded spaces don't contain *multiple* adjacent spaces (see the bottom section for why your *first* attempt with `"%1"` instead of `\"%1\"` didn't work).

To **make the command robust** (and also more efficient), use the following variation, which **does *not* involve `cmd.exe`** (because it isn't necessary), and **the command to pass to PowerShell is enclosed in `"..."` *as a whole*** with **embedded `"` escaped as `\"`** (as in your attempt):

```
powershell.exe -noprofile -command "Remove-Item -LiteralPath \"%1\" -Recurse -Force"
```

**PowerShell CLI options used:**

- `-noprofile` suppresses loading of the current user's profile (`$PROFILE`), which would only unnecessarily slow down the command (or, worse, could change its behavior).
- `-command` tells PowerShell that the remaining arguments are a PowerShell command (a piece of source code, as distinct from `-file`, which is used to invoke a *script*)

  - While you don't strictly need to specify `-command` in Windows PowerShell, because it is *implied*, that is no longer the case in PowerShell *Core*, which defaults to `-file`.

**The `Remove-Item` command passed to PowerShell:**

- **Enclosing the *entire* PowerShell command in `"..."` ensures that whitespace inside the command is preserved as-is**, which matters with paths that happen to contain runs of multiple spaces, e.g. `"c:\Users\jdoe\Invoices<space><space>2018"`
- **`\"` is how PowerShell requires *nested* (embedded) `"` chars. with to be escaped *when called from the command line* with `-command`** - see below for an explanation.
- `-LiteralPath` ensures that `Remove-Item` interprets the path *literally* rather than as a *wildcard pattern* (as would happen by default, with the implied `-Path` parameter); while not very likely, paths such as `c:\tmp\folder[]` would break the command if taken as a wildcard.

**Caveats**:

- Due to (ultimately) using double quotes (`"..."`) to enclose the path (the directory path that File Explorer expands `%1` to), it becomes an *expandable string*, i.e., it is subject to *string interpolation*, which means that folder paths that contain `$` characters (e.g., `c:\tmp\$foo`) could be misinterpreted.
- You can suppress this interpolation by replacing `\"%1\"` with `'%1'`, i.e., by using a *single-quoted* string (which PowerShell always treats literally), but the problem is that you then won't be able to use the command on folders whose paths happen to have `'` chars. in them (e.g., `c:\tmp\o'reilly`)

---

#### Why just `"%1"` isn't enough:

`cmd /c PowerShell Remove-Item "%1" -recurse -force`, your (first) command line (which you're using as a **command definition for File Explorer's context menus**), is processed as follows:

- File Explorer replaces `%1` with the absolute path of the file for folder that was right-clicked, as-is - whether or not the path has embedded spaces; e.g.:

  - `c:\Users\jdoe\Invoices 2018`.
- The resulting command line is then executed; e.g.:

  - `cmd /c PowerShell Remove-Item "c:\Users\jdoe\Invoices 2018" -recurse -force`
- `cmd /c` is incidental here (and not needed): It essentially just relays the command line to PowerShell (via its executable, `powershell.exe`); e.g.:

  - `powershell.exe Remove-Item "c:\Users\jdoe\Invoices 2018" -recurse -force`
- **PowerShell *first* processes the individual arguments - `Remove-Item`, `"c:\Users\jdoe\Invoices 2018"`, `-recurse`, `-force` by *removing enclosing double quotes***.
- **Since the `-command` option is implied, the *quote-stripped* arguments are re-joined with a space as the separator and *then* interpreted as a *snippet of PowerShell source code***; e.g.:

  - `Remove-Item c:\Users\jdoe\Invoices 2018 -recurse -force`
  - As you can see, the removal of the double quotes resulted in a broken PowerShell command, because the path with spaces now lacks quoting so that `c:\Users\jdoe\Invoices 2018` is no longer recognized as a *single* argument and is instead interpreted as *2* arguments, prefix `c:\Users\jdoe\Invoices` followed by `2018` as its own, syntactically extraneous argument.
  - While using `\"%1\"` instead of `"%1"` alone would prevent the up-front quote stripping - by telling PowerShell that the `"` chars. are to be *retained* during initial argument parsing - additionally enclosing the *entire PowerShell command* in `"..."` is necessary to correctly preserve file paths with *multiple adjacent spaces* (even though such paths may be the result of a typo during folder creation):

    - *Without* overall enclosing `"..."`, a `\"`-quoted path such as `C:\Users\jdoe\Invoices<space><space>2018` would result in the following *2* arguments:

      - `\"C:\Users\jdoe\Invoices`
      - `2018\"`
      - When PowerShell later re-joins the individual arguments with a *single* space between them (after having recognized `\"` as an *escaped* `"` to be *retained*), *before* interpreting the resulting string as PowerShell code, it sees `"C:\Users\jdoe\Invoices<space>2018"`, i.e., only a *single* space.
    - *With* overall enclosing `"..."`, the entire PowerShell command is parsed as a *single* argument, with *interior whitespace preserved as-is*, which avoids the problem.